# конвертировать из canvas в base64

Tags: html, excel, canvas, диаграммы, base64

доброго дня) столкнулся с проблемой что нужно вывести график chart.js в эксель.
Сам график на странице отображается как canvas, чтобы работать с ним мне нужно его как то перевести в base64) есть у кого какие мысли как это реализовать, может есть библиотеки какие?)

Comment: поможет это или нет : https://gist.github.com/gfcarvalho/9502621

Comment: хм выглядит интересно, спасибо щас буду пробовать)

Comment: `function imageToBase64(img)
{
    var canvas = $('#myChart');
    var ctx, dataURL, base64;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    base64 = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
    return base64;
} `

у меня <canvas id="myChart" ></canvas> 
как думаете, целесообразно будет сделать так? или логично вообще?

Comment: я вообще канву ни разу в base64 не делал ... не было такой задачи ... канвас он же сам по себе картинка

Comment: @МаксимЛенский хм, хорошо, у меня график же, и постоянно разные значения при разных кликах на параметры, и вот мне нужно грубо говоря скрин этого графика) и данный график в canvas )

Answer (score 1):

получил у canvas - base64

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>    

// находим canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
// получаем контекст
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
// рисуем что-нибудь
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 1.5 * Math.PI, 0.5 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.stroke();
// получаем base64
console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
```

это пример тестовый, вы можете передавать свои значения)